# iOS app cannot render a particular question

Tags: bug, ios-app

I frequently use the iOS app on both an iPhone 5s and 6 plus, and find it convenient.

But there is one question that keeps crashing the app: [Does Newton's third law apply to momentum or to forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143015/26969)

Every time somebody comments and I want to see what happens, I find that the app quits. There must be some incompatibility - maybe the Q&A is too long, maybe there is some crazy markdown, maybe it's because there's a bonus attached...

I wonder if others find the same problem with this question. Initially it was OK but in the last couple of days not.

Comment: Does it happen in any other question?

Comment: I haven't noticed it on any other question...

Comment: No repro here, just loaded the question, all answers, and all comments using the app. Can you give direct link to one of the comments crashing your app? I have iPhone 4S (iOS 8.1.1) but doubt it matter.

Comment: It (still) happens when I click this link (on my iPhone... posting this on a computer!) http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/320925?noredirect=1 . I wonder if there is some problem with a cache. Is there a way to flush it?

Comment: No crash for me, but it just keeps loading forever. Hmm... let's see if [this link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143015/does-newtons-third-law-apply-to-momentum-or-to-forces/152771?noredirect=1#comment320925_152771) makes any difference

Comment: Weird. Can you try clicking the link in my previous comment via the app? Works fine for me, while your link doesn't work. :/

Comment: I did - it crashed (not immediately: it takes a few seconds)

Comment: OK then, time to let the dev team handle it, out of ideas. (you did try to restart the iPhone device, did you? :))

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Dev team - you know how to find me.

Comment: Taking a look at this...

Comment: @Floris could you tell me what device and iOS version you are using to reproduce this?

Comment: iPhone 6+ with 16G RAM and 8.1.1 ; it was also happening on a 5s with 7.1.2 and 64 G RAM but today that device won't even load the question when I click the link in the comment above...